# Email Composer in android

Tags: android, email

In my application i want send a email to one account.in one button click event.i used the below code . this have exception

```
public void onClick(View v) {
             sendEmail(context, new String[]{"jayampalaniraja@gmail.com"}, "Sending Email", "Test Email", "I am body");
        }

        private void sendEmail(Context context, String[] recipientList,
                String subject, String body, String title) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipientList);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

            try
            {
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, title));

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }   
        }
```

The exception I am getting as

```
 "03-19 19:13:19.553: I/System.out(2010): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
```

Comment: The exception is  "03-19 19:13:19.553: I/System.out(2010): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

Comment: 03-19 19:13:19.553: I/System.out(2010): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: I have this exception..how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine. first thing to configure a  email client for your emulator.`enter code here`

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            String aEmailList[] = { "pal@Yahoo.co.in" };
            //String aEmailCCList[] = { ""};
            //String aEmailBCCList[] = { "" };

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
            //emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, aEmailCCList);
            //emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, aEmailBCCList);

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");

            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My message body.");
               try
               {
            startActivity(emailIntent);
               }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(about.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


               catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void sendEmail(Context context, String[] recipientList,
                String subject, String body, String title) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipientList);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            try
            {
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, title));

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }   
        }
```