# Call a non-static method from static inner class

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android, I'm facing this problem that when I call a non-static method from static inner class I have nullPointerException, Below is my code.

```
public void playPauseMusic() {
    // check for already playing
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.pause();
            // Changing button image to play button
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
        }
    } else {
        // Resume surah
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.start();
            // Changing button image to pause button
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
        }
    }
}

public static class notifyPlayPauseListner extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("PLAY/Pause Tag","In the listener Play/Pause  ");
        MainActivity mc = new MainActivity();
        mc.playPauseMusic();
    }
}
```

May be its a simple concept but I'm new to android that's why asking. Kindly Help

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MainActivity mc = new MainActivity();
```

Instantiating a new activity doesn't make any sense. Instead, you need to *find* the existing instance of `MainActivity` and call it's desired method.

Also, using an activity to play music isn't really a good idea. Consider using a [service](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, this part of your code does not work as you expect it:

```
MainActivity mc = new MainActivity();
mc.playPauseMusic();
```

This actually creates a new instance of `MainActivity`, and calls its method `playPauseMusic()`. The new `MainActivity`s `mp` is null, so accessing it leads to the NPE.

The problem is, `new MainActivity();` does not return an already running instance of the activity, as you seem to be expecting. Even worse: That's not the way you instantiate an `Activity`. Usually, `Activity`s are started via `Intents` that are resolved by the system. All instantiation of the `Activity` is done by the system, and that's the only way for the `Activity` to get its `Context`.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218476/starting-activity-from-broadcastreceiver) on how to start `Activity`s from a `BroadcastReceiver`, if that's what you want. Also note that playing music in the background from an `Activity` is a bad idea. Using a `Service` is recommended.